# Number of possible solutions for this repeated commutative, non-associative operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, nonassociative-algebras

> If we define $x^n=\overbrace{x\star x\star\cdots\star x}^{n\text{ copies of }x},\; a\star b=-(a+b)$, where the final expression is evaluated with the usual definitions of $+$ and $-$, how many possible values are there for $x^n$, where the expression can be parenthesized in any way?

For $n\in\{1,2,3\}$, it's just one ($x$, $-2x$, $x$, respectively), but when $n=4$, there are two ($-2x$ and $4x$). I don't even know what to search for this, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: If you get two or three more terms, a search on OEIS may prove fruitful.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. For $n = 3$, one gets either $x(xx) = x(-(x+x))$ or $(xx)x = (-(x+x))x$. How do you conclude that the unique possible value is $x$?

Comment: Here, $xx$ is defined as the negative of the sum of the operands, so those are both equal to $-(x-(x+x)) = -(x-2x) = -(-x) = x$. I'll make it a bit clearer in the question.

Comment: Much clearer indeed! Thanks.